# Got this error POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyAIAPVIvYAy4K20V5KgrEj4VESZ55ch6II 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to upload signup data like image in firestore. I have setup firestore and storage in firebase although it gives this error.
"POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyAIAPVIvYAy4K20V5KgrEj4VESZ55ch6II 400"

what to do ? Can anyone please help?

My signup page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, FormGroup } from "reactstrap";
import Helmet from "../components/Helmet/Helmet";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

import { auth } from "../firebase.config";
import { storage } from "../firebase.config";
import { db } from "../firebase.config";

import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "../styles/login.css";

const Signup = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const signupUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );

      const user = userCredential.user;

      const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${Date.now() + username}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

      uploadTask.on(
        (error) => {
          toast.error(error.message);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(updateProfile.snapshot.ref).then(
            async (downloadURL) => {
              await updateProfile(user, {
                displayName: username,
                photoURL: downloadURL,
              });
              await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
                uid: user.uid,
                displayName: username,
                email,
                photoURL: downloadURL,
              });
            }
          );
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("something went wrong");
    }
  };
  return (
    <Helmet title="Signup">
      <section>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="6" className="m-auto text-center">
              <h3 className="fw-bold mb-2">Signup</h3>

              <Form className="auth__form" onSubmit={signupUser}>
                <FormGroup className="form__group">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="username"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup className="form__group">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup className="form__group">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup className="form__group">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
                  />
                </FormGroup>

                <button type="submit" className="buy__btn auth__btn">
                  Create an account
                </button>
                <p>
                  Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </p>
              </Form>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>
    </Helmet>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

I think I have configured firebase correctly.